# Differentiating between store changes in Flux?

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

I have two views (`A`, `B`) that listen to a store (`S`), so if the store changes, it emits a change to both views.

Let's say both `A` and `B` send actions (`X` and `Y` respectively) to update `S`. `A` is suppose to update on the change that `X` made, but not on `Y`'s and vice versa for `B`.

However, because of race conditions, I don't know what order `X` or `Y` finishes and because `S` simply emits a change without differentiating whether the change was caused by `X` or `Y`, I don't know whether to update `A` or `B`.  So when `S` emits a change event, how would I be able to figure out which view to update (`A` or `B`, i.e. which action happened [`X` or `Y`]?) using `Flux`?

Comment: Make sure your state is immutable and then compare `this.props` and `nextProps` in [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).

Comment: @glortho I'm not sure how this relates to my issue.  I've updated my question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?  What glortho is referring to is that you should not need to know which action it is caused by.  The store should change the global state, and that React should be able to figure out what needs to change based on diffing that state.

Answer (score 0):

Register two different action handlers for `X` and `Y` in the store. Set a `lastChangeFrom` string property on the store to respectively equal `'x'` or `'y'`.

Then, check the `nextProps.store.lastChangeFrom` property in your React component's `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` function:

```
// Component A
// listens for changes from action X
React.createClass({
    // ...


    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextState.lastChangeFrom == 'x';
    }

    // ...
});

// Component B
// listens for changes from action Y
React.createClass({
    // ...

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextState.lastChangeFrom == 'y';
    }

    // ...
});
```

This way, both Component `A` and `B` will receive updates from the store but will only process them if the origin is the respective action.

Keep in mind that the store itself will still reflect all updates, regardless from their originating action. E.g. triggering different updates from `Y` multiple times, then triggering another update from `X` will apply the store state from all intermediate updates to Component `A`.

This answer assumes you're using [Facebook's flux dispatcher / pattern](https://github.com/facebook/flux). Other flux libraries such as [flummox](http://acdlite.github.io/flummox/) may behave differently, e.g. changes from stores would come in via `nextProps` instead of `nextState`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using EventEmitter2 for the Store which allows for namespaced events. The store can emit a change.x in response to X action, and change.Y in response to Y action. Likewise, your views A and B can now differentiate between the change events.